# How to test “verification flow” code? would you test this at all or just the individual checkers?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I want to write unit-test to my code

however while writing it, it seems all I can verify is that one method or the other were called once.

My class is a manager that execute verification flow.

It calls many checkers\verifiers - so they have the real logic.

How do you advise me to test such "verification flow" code?

my code:

```
public AlternativeShortTotalChecker(SegmentsIdsChecker segmentsIdsChecker, InstructionsChecker instructionsChecker,
                                    RouteNameChecker routeNameChecker, AlternativeDistanceChecker
                                            alternativeDistanceChecker, AlternativeTimeChecker
                                            alternativeTimeChecker,
                                    IDeltaFromBaselineGenerator deltaFromBaselineGenerator,
                                    AStarVisitedChecker aStarVisitedChecker, GlobalSettings globalSettings) {
    this.segmentsIdsChecker = segmentsIdsChecker;
    this.instructionsChecker = instructionsChecker;
    this.routeNameChecker = routeNameChecker;
    this.alternativeDistanceChecker = alternativeDistanceChecker;
    this.alternativeTimeChecker = alternativeTimeChecker;
    this.deltaFromBaselineGenerator = deltaFromBaselineGenerator;
    this.aStarVisitedChecker = aStarVisitedChecker;
    this.globalSettings = globalSettings;
}


public List<String> checkAllAlternativesShort(CompleteRoutingResponseShort baselineRoutingResponse,
                                              CompleteRoutingResponseShort
                                                      routingResponse) {
    int numOfAlts = routingResponse.alternatives.size();
    List<String> testFailureMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfAlts; i++) {
        ResponseShort currentResponse = getAlternativeShort(routingResponse, i).response;
        ResponseShort baselineResponse = getAlternativeShort(baselineRoutingResponse, i).response;
        AlternativeShort alternativeShort = getAlternativeShort(routingResponse, i);
        String testFailureMessage = checkAlternative(alternativeShort.alternative_regression_id, currentResponse,
                baselineResponse);
        testFailureMessages.add(testFailureMessage);
    }
    return testFailureMessages;
}

private AlternativeShort getAlternativeShort(CompleteRoutingResponseShort routingResponse, int i) {
    return routingResponse.alternatives.get(i);
}

private String checkAlternative(String currentAltId, ResponseShort currentResponse,
                                ResponseShort baselineResponse) {
    IndividualStat individualStat = new IndividualStat(currentAltId);
    aStarVisitedChecker.setForAltDiff(globalSettings.astarVisited_altDiffHighThreshold);
    individualStat.aStarVisitedDelta = aStarVisitedChecker.checkAStarCountPerAlt(currentResponse, baselineResponse);

    individualStat.segmentsIdsDelta = segmentsIdsChecker.checkSegmentsIdsUnorderedIdentity(currentResponse,
            baselineResponse);
    switch (individualStat.segmentsIdsDelta.delta) {
        case IDENTICAL: {
            individualStat.areInstructionsIdentical = instructionsChecker.checkTotalInstructionIdentity
                    (currentResponse, baselineResponse);
            individualStat.areRouteNamesIdentical = routeNameChecker.checkRouteNameIdentity(currentResponse,
                    baselineResponse);
            break;
        }
        case SMALL:
        case LARGE: {
            individualStat.distancesDelta = alternativeDistanceChecker.checkTotalDistanceIdentity
                    (currentResponse, baselineResponse);
            individualStat.timesDelta = alternativeTimeChecker.checkTotalTimeIdentity(currentResponse,
                    baselineResponse);
            break;
        }
    }
    return deltaFromBaselineGenerator.addDeltaForSpecificAlternative(individualStat);
}
```

my try for UT. Would you skip testing this code?

```
@Test
public void checkAltWith2() throws Exception {
    DescriptiveDelta descriptiveDelta = new DescriptiveDelta();
    descriptiveDelta.delta = Delta.IDENTICAL;
    when(segmentsIdsCheckerMock.checkSegmentsIdsUnorderedIdentity(any(ResponseShort.class), any(ResponseShort
            .class)))
            .thenReturn(descriptiveDelta);

    AlternativeShortTotalChecker alternativeShortTotalChecker =
            new AlternativeShortTotalCheckerBuilder()
                    .setAlternativeDistanceChecker(alternativeDistanceCheckerMock)
                    .setAlternativeTimeChecker(alternativeTimeCheckerMock)
                    .setAStarVisitedChecker(aStarVisitedCheckerMock)
                    .setDeltaFromBaselineGenerator(deltaFromBaselineGeneratorMock)
                    .setGlobalSettings(globalSettings)
                    .setInstructionsChecker(instructionsCheckerMock)
                    .setRouteNameChecker(routeNameCheckerMock)
                    .setSegmentsIdsChecker(segmentsIdsCheckerMock)
                    .createAlternativeShortTotalChecker();


    CompleteRoutingResponseShort currentResponse = routingResponsesInMemoryFactory.getOneAlternative();
    CompleteRoutingResponseShort baselineResponse = routingResponsesInMemoryFactory.getOneAlternative();

    alternativeShortTotalChecker.checkAllAlternativesShort(currentResponse, baselineResponse);

    verify(aStarVisitedCheckerMock).checkAStarCountPerAlt(any(ResponseShort.class), any(ResponseShort.class));
    verify(segmentsIdsCheckerMock).checkSegmentsIdsUnorderedIdentity(any(ResponseShort.class), any(ResponseShort
            .class));
    verify(instructionsCheckerMock).checkTotalInstructionIdentity(any(ResponseShort.class), any(ResponseShort
            .class));
    verify(routeNameCheckerMock).checkRouteNameIdentity(any(ResponseShort.class), any(ResponseShort.class));

    verify(alternativeDistanceCheckerMock, times(0)).checkTotalDistanceIdentity(any(ResponseShort.class), any
            (ResponseShort.class));
    verify(alternativeTimeCheckerMock, times(0)).checkTotalTimeIdentity(any(ResponseShort.class), any
            (ResponseShort.class));
}
```

Comment: I think what you're doing is fine. Not all classes produce concrete results but are important for orchestration and it's good to test these and verifying the orchestration is the right way to do it.

Comment: consider using Annotations (InjectMocks and Mock) if available to you to simplify the test setup too

Comment: Your question is not be specific enough; you are asking us to carefully analyze your code and unit test to understand if it makes sense or  should be changed. Not many people around here will be willing to do that. My personal two cent: you code looks quite complex; and it is no surprise that the corresponding unit test looks overly complex, too. My recommendation: order "Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship" by Robert Martin. Read it two or three times. Start practicing. And in a year from now, your code will be better. (That is what worked for me and my unit tests).

Comment: @EddyG i don't think I can simplify my code. At the end of the day there should be a "flow manager" - that only delegates work to other verifier. no?

Comment: @user1065869 What I am saying is: two years ago, I would have probably written similar code than you have. Many months of studying and practicing clean code; I do believe that my code is now much better structured; easier to grasp; and easier to test. And as I also try to apply TDD ... "test" "drives" my "development"; meaning: my unit tests become simpler because I write my classes in a way that makes it easier to test them. But this is nothing that can be explained here ...